# How to avoid duplicate usage of Users from CSV file in JMeter

Tags: performance, csv, duplicates, jmeter, load

I'm performing load test using JMeter with the following flow:

- Thread Group which consists of multiple users, infinite loop for 5 minutes.    (Image in the next link->[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zUN0.png))
- CSV config file that has the following configuration ([in this link CSV config)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmvbe.png)

So, my plan is:

- Getting users from a CSV file (inside the CSV, each row has username).
- Having a loop controller which inside there is:

  - Once only controller which is for my Login request.
  - Transactions depending on session validity (that's why I have the loop controller).

The question is - I receive a lot of multiple session errors so I want to make sure that I am configuring right my test to avoid a situation where a user from a previous thread loop haven't finished the flow, but the second thread loop began and took the details of that certain user from the CSV file leading to an invalid session to the first run.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can overcome this situation by providing enough number of credentials i.e.,

```
number of credentials = number of threads.
```

so, each thread can pick a unique username and password and thus avoid the conflict of multiple sessions of the same user.

---

JMeter would reuse the credentials if there are not sufficient entries in the CSV file. i.e., `Recycle on EOF, default value set to True.` (in **CSV DataSet Config**). so if you provided less number of credentials, then JMeter start reusing the values from beginning for later threads. Unless the AUT (application under test) supports multiple sessions for the same credentials, you can't use less number of credentials. Turning off the setting `Recycle on EOF`, results in lack of credentials for the later users (threads), thus causing the JMeter to stop those threads.

---

how CSV values are read:

> By default, the file is only opened once, and each thread will use a different line from the file. However the order in which lines are passed to threads depends on the order in which they execute, which may vary between iterations. Lines are read at the start of each test iteration. The file name and mode are resolved in the first iteration.

If you want to have values specific to each thread:

> If you want each thread to have its own set of values, then you will need to create a set of files, one for each thread. For example test1.csv, test2.csv, …, testn.csv. Use the filename test${__threadNum}.csv and set the "Sharing mode" to "Current thread"

Reference:

1. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config